# Configure nginx with support for multi subdomain and upstream

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass, nginx-config, server-name

I have been trying to setup nginx as a proxy wherein request is routed to upstream based on subdomain. I hope example makes it more clear

```
upstream ubuntu {
  server  www.ubuntu.com:443;
}
upstream google {
  server  www.google.com:443;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl ;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/client-certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/client-certs/server.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
        resolver 127.0.0.1 ipv6=off;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name ~^(.*)\.test\.com$;

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://$1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

so if i request https://google.test.com it should go to https://www.google.com

With this current setup nginx returns me 404 for any of the site that i query. Though i can see that request goes to my queried upstream site(in this case google.com).

Not getting if am missing anything.

Comment: You probably need to set the Host header.

Comment: The upstream directive is for routing to a group of servers, not a single server. You are specifying an upstream server using the domain name, yet you have no resolver directive...

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried adding setting host header but i am still not able to make it work.

proxy_set_header Host $1;

Comment: @miknik couldn't quite understand on _yet you have no resolver directive_
I have a local resolver running which should take care of it i suppose. Can you please explain it.

Comment: The upstream server probably needs the Host header to be set to something sensible like `www.example.com`, so with your existing scheme, that would be `proxy_set_header Host www.$1.com;`

Comment: @avaj from the documentation, the resolver directive Configures name servers used to resolve names of upstream servers into addresses.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried playing around with setting up host headers but result is still the same.

Comment: @miknik upstreams are getting resolved.